# Applying ckeditor to a textarea

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to add the (inline) CKEditor 5 to an existing django project.

From what I understand the inline version does not work with textarea elements but rather with div's. However the django forms do not have div widgets. I'm not entirely sure what is the best way to proceed from here. I can make the editable div show up using the steps in [the documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html#Inline-editor). But how do I associate it with a form and / or pass the text on to my views?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this manually with django, there's already a package you can import to your project:  https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor.

You can see other WYSIWYG editor django integrations at https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Comment: I have been looking through the documentation of the django-ckeditor app and I can't seem to find anything about the inline version. Is this functionality included or does it only support the classic version?